# AngularJS Directive Issue retrieving template from templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, scope, angularjs-directive

I'm new to creating directives in angular, and I'm kind of stuck here, I want to create a basic mini calendar directive to select a date in a given month.
I'm still getting error from the template when it's requested.
Any help? Thanks

> ```
> function calendarController($scope) {
> $scope.config = new Date(2000, 0, 1); } angular.module("calendar", []).directive('miniCalendar', function($parse) {
> return {
>     restrict: "E",
>     replace: true,
>     templateUrl: "../views/template.html",
>     transclude: true,
>     controller: mCalBinding,
>     compile: function(element, attrs) {
>         debugger;
>         var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
>         return function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
>             var processChange = function() {
>                 // var date = new Date(element.datepicker("getDate"));
>                 scope.$apply(function(scope) {
>                     // Change bound variable
>                     debugger;
>                     modelAccessor.assign(scope, date);
>                 });
>             };
>             element.datepicker({
>                 inline: true,
>                 onClose: processChange,
>                 onSelect: processChange
>             });
>             // scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function(val) {
>             //     return true;
>             // });
>
>         };
>
>     }
> }; });
>
> function mCalBinding($scope) {
> //Binding of the directive
> $scope.currentDate = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
> $scope.prev = function(data) {
>
> };
> $scope.next = function(data) {
>
> };
> $scope.currentMonth = 'December';
> $scope.currentYear = '2679';
> $scope.days = [{
>     day: "1"
> }, {
>     day: "2"
> }, {
>     day: "3"
> }, {
>     day: "4"
> }, {
>     day: "5"
> }, {
>     day: "6"
> }, {
>     day: "7"
> }, {
>     day: "8"
> }, {
>     day: "9"
> }, {
>     day: "10"
> }, {
>     day: "11"
> }, {
>     day: "12"
> }, {
>     day: "13"
> }];
> $scope.weeks = [{
>     week: "1",
>     days: [{
>         day: "1"
>     }, {
>         day: "2"
>     }, {
>         day: "3"
>     }, {
>         day: "4"
>     }, {
>         day: "5"
>     }, {
>         day: "6"
>     }, {
>         day: "7"
>     }, {
>         day: "8"
>     }, {
>         day: "9"
>     }, {
>         day: "10"
>     }, {
>         day: "11"
>     }, {
>         day: "12"
>     }, {
>         day: "13"
>     }]
> }, {
>     week: "2",
>     days: [{
>         day: "1"
>     }, {
>         day: "2"
>     }, {
>         day: "3"
>     }, {
>         day: "4"
>     }, {
>         day: "5"
>     }, {
>         day: "6"
>     }, {
>         day: "7"
>     }, {
>         day: "8"
>     }, {
>         day: "9"
>     }, {
>         day: "10"
>     }, {
>         day: "11"
>     }, {
>         day: "12"
>     }, {
>         day: "13"
>     }]
> }, {
>     week: "3",
>     days: [{
>         day: "1"
>     }, {
>         day: "2"
>     }, {
>         day: "3"
>     }, {
>         day: "4"
>     }, {
>         day: "5"
>     }, {
>         day: "6"
>     }, {
>         day: "7"
>     }, {
>         day: "8"
>     }, {
>         day: "9"
>     }, {
>         day: "10"
>     }, {
>         day: "11"
>     }, {
>         day: "12"
>     }, {
>         day: "13"
>     }]
> }, {
>     week: "4",
>     days: [{
>         day: "1"
>     }, {
>         day: "2"
>     }, {
>         day: "3"
>     }, {
>         day: "4"
>     }, {
>         day: "5"
>     }, {
>         day: "6"
>     }, {
>         day: "7"
>     }, {
>         day: "8"
>     }, {
>         day: "9"
>     }, {
>         day: "10"
>     }, {
>         day: "11"
>     }, {
>         day: "12"
>     }, {
>         day: "13"
>     }]
> }]; } /* Fragment End - directive */
> ```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="calendar" ng-controller="calendarController" class="ng-scope">
    <mini-calendar type="text" ng-model="config" /> </div>
```

and the template:

```
<input type="text" ng-bind="currentDate">
<div >
    <div >
        <a>
            <span ng-click="prev">Prev</span>
        </a>
        <a>
            <span ng-click="next">Next</span>
        </a>
        <div >
            <span ng-bind="currentMonth">January</span>&nbsp;
            <span ng-bind="currentYear">2000</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="day in days">
                    <span ng-bind="day"></span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="week in weeks">
            <td ng-repeat="day in days">
                <a ng-bind="day" ng-click="selectDate">1</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can i see the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably get this error [https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt/](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile/tplrt/)

> When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and
>   replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That
>   is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the
>   templateUrl must be contained within a single html element.
>
> For example, `<p>blah <em>blah</em> blah</p>` instead of simply blah
>   `<em>blah</em>` blah. Otherwise, the replacement operation would result
>   in a single element (the directive) being replaced with multiple
>   elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly needed in
>   practice.

What I recommend is to avoid using the `replace` flag at all.

It is now (1.3.x) deprecated and will be removed in the next major version anyway:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb